# question about C const

Tags: c, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [about “int const *p” and “const int *p ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268521/about-int-const-p-and-const-int-p)

Difference between

```
const  char *p
```

and

```
char * const p?
```

is that fist one means cannot change char. Later one means cannot change the pointer. Am I right? 
Thank you!

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but close enough that it should answer your question.

Comment: Just read them backwards: "p is a pointer to a char that is constant", "p is a constant pointer to a char".

Comment: @Jim Balter, That fails for `char const * p`.

Comment: @ikegami No, it doesn't. "p is a pointer to a constant char" and "p is a pointer to a char that is constant" mean the same thing and so do the declarations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
const char *p
```

means the characters cannot be changed. `*p = '\0'` is illegal. Var `p` is a pointer to a `const char`.

```
char * const p
```

means the pointer cannot be changed. `p = 0` is illegal. Constant `p` is a pointer to a `char`.

```
const char * const p
```

means neither can be changed. Constant `p` is a pointer to a `const char`.

**Update**: Added third declaration.

Answer (score 3):

In the first you can't edit the pointee and in the second you can't edit the pointer.
Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#Pointers_and_references) perhaps.